# Fastest way to get the PID of the current running terminal and save to a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic

I need to get the PID of each open terminal.

I have something in the works right now. However, it doesn't give the correct PID, and it's a little slow.

```
@echo off
rem Note: Session Name for privileged Administrative consoles is sometimes blank.
if not defined SESSIONNAME set SESSIONNAME=Console

setlocal
set instance=%DATE% %TIME% %RANDOM%
title %instance%

rem PID Find
for /f "usebackq tokens=2" %%a in (`tasklist /FO list /FI "SESSIONNAME eq %SESSIONNAME%" /FI "USERNAME eq %USERNAME%" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %instance%" ^| find /i "PID:"`) do set PID=%%a
if not defined PID for /f "usebackq tokens=2" %%a in (`tasklist /FO list /FI "SESSIONNAME eq %SESSIONNAME%" /FI "USERNAME eq %USERNAME%" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator:  %instance%" ^| find /i "PID:"`) do set PID=%%a
if not defined PID echo !Error: Could not get PID of current process.  Exiting.& exit /b 1

echo Here's the PID: %PID%
```

I'm not sure how to explain it, but whenever this runs, it doesn't give the PID of the `cmd.exe`, but it returns the PID of the overall process itself. So if I ran the normal `cmd`, it will return the right PID, but if I ran a different terminal like `Cmder`, it will give the PID of the `Cmder`, not its affiliated `cmd.exe`.

I've seen a lot of solutions that use a `for` loop with `wmic`, but I can't seem to get it to work. Every time I try it, the PID it returns is always different each time I run it, which is obviously wrong.

I can use the following, and it works with 3rd party terminals AND is faster than what I have above:

```
wmic process where "name='WMIC.exe'" get parentprocessid
```

I'm just not sure how I can extract the PID out of the output of this. Is there any quicker way of getting the PID of a terminal?

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/getCmdPID.bat) . It will return the current PID into the errorlevel

Comment: check also this [thread](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6133)

Comment: Your wmic command will get you the required ParentProcessID if you don't run it inside a for loop which effectively starts another cmd.exe process. You may find it easier to /OUTPUT the WMIC command then read the output back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the idea in my comment:

```bat
WMIC /OUTPUT:temp.txt Process Where "Caption='WMIC.exe'" Get ParentProcessID
For /F "Skip=1" %%A In ('Type temp.txt') Do If Not Defined PID Set "PID=%%A"
Del temp.txt
Echo=%PID%
```

You can adjust your WMIC command, to use `Where "CommandLine Like…`if you feel that there's a possibility of another WMIC process running. That will probably add a small time increase though.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that "each open terminal" means cmd.exe processes.

```
PS C:\src\powershell> (Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "Name='cmd.exe'").ProcessId
6340
6204
```

Is there something that needs to be done with these PIDs?

Yes, you can use this in a cmd.exe shell script.

```
C:>powershell "(Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter \"Name='cmd.exe'\").ProcessId"
```